# Unable to reconnect with Hornet, Wildfly, JMS

Tags: java, jms, wildfly

I am trying to use JMS with wildfly but getting this error in wildfly server log. Can anyone tell me whats wrong I am doing?

```
2015-05-27 17:10:09,292 ERROR [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 4) HQ154003: Unable to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@19213379 connectionFactoryLookup=null destination=queue/freightdesk.xmlintmanager.inbound destinationType=javax.jms.Queue selector=MESSAGETYPE = 'ORHFA' ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile.define(ClassFile.java:282)
at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractClassFactory.defineClass(AbstractClassFactory.java:164)
at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractClassFactory.newInstance(AbstractClassFactory.java:225)
at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.ProxyFactory.newInstance(ProxyFactory.java:270)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.JBossMessageEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(JBossMessageEndpointFactory.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.JBossMessageEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(JBossMessageEndpointFactory.java:62)
at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.setup(HornetQMessageHandler.java:198) [hornetq-ra-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation.setup(HornetQActivation.java:340) [hornetq-ra-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation.handleFailure(HornetQActivation.java:768) [hornetq-ra-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation$SetupActivation.run(HornetQActivation.java:823) [hornetq-ra-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:219)
at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:828)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile.define(ClassFile.java:277)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.freightdesk.fdfoliox.organization.mdb.XMLOrgFindAddListener$$$endpoint11 overrides final method onMessage.(Ljavax/jms/Message;)V
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check the default constructor of your service implementation classes**. Make sure it's public.

The stack trace shows that it tried to perform a `new MyServiceImpl()` using reflection (i.e. `MyServiceImpl.class.newInstance()`). Given the fact that it failed, it could be because there was no public constructor.

```
class MyServiceImpl extends MyService
{
    public MyServiceImpl(){}
}
```

Comment: I checked my wildfly server settings and made them correct. Finally resolved

Comment: @NarendraChamoli what was the problem ?

Comment: I was unable to write correct hornet-server setting under Messaging domain of standalone. Where I was using netty-connector which use stomp acceptor, and the protocol is STOMP (all capital). In JBoss it was not the case.